# Can a file that's being supplied by bind-mount support overwriting via `mv`?

Tags: files, filesystems, bind-mount

Suppose I bind-mount file `a` atop file `b`...

```bash
$ echo 'line 1' > a
$ touch b
$ mount --bind a b
```

The initial file contents will be mirrored at both paths, as expected:

```bash
$ cat a
line 1

$ cat b
line 1
```

And if I concatenate to either path, the new contents will be mirrored both ways, as expected:

```bash
$ echo 'line 2' >> a

$ cat a
line 1
line 2

$ cat b
line 1
line 2

$ echo 'line 3' >> b

$ cat a
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ cat b
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

However, I can't overwrite `b` via `mv`:

```bash
$ echo 'totally new contents' > temp
$ mv tmp b
mv: can't rename 'tmp': Device or resource busy
```

Is there a way to get this to work so that the new contents are mirrored at `a`?

---

The reason I want to do this has to do with the way my system's filesystem is set up.

It's an embedded system, so most of the filesystem is mounted read-only. Certain 3rd-party services try to write to hard-coded files like `/etc/machine-info` or `/etc/hostname`, which doesn't work because they're read-only. Our normal way of working around this is to have a writable partition containing just the files that we expect to be modified, and then bind-mount those writable files onto the traditional Linux paths where the services can find them.

This works when the process opens the file for writing and modifies it in-place. But, as described above, it doesn't work when the process does the equivalent of `mv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a and b are involved in a mount point, you can't use `mv`.
However, you could overwrite it with `cp`.

Or, instead of bind mounting onto b, you could bind mount the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Mount**ed** points cannot be moved or deleted, they are basically immutable.

You can mount something on top of them however.

`mv` also breaks hard links if they existed previously.